# How trigger an event that's out reach from the current class?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, eventtrigger

In C# WinForms, I have created a User Control and, for the sake of this example, let's suppose that inside it I have created a button and it trigger an event when I click on it.

I add this custom user control in real-time in my current form. Problem. When I click on the button (which is inside the user control) I don't know how to update the event in my current Form. Anyone know how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time I provide an answer, so I hope I'm doing it right. All your other answers were helped but I feel they were vague (probably to a vague question). I tried to provide the solution more clearly as possible. Feel free to improve it if something is wrong, and tell me if it should be marked a 'accepted'. Thanks for your support everyone!

First, in the UserControl I created a button and Button1Click is delegated to it:

```
this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 17);
this.button1.Name = "button1";
this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(95, 23);
this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
this.button1.Text = "Click";
this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1Click);
```

Later in the source of UserControl:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now, in the MainForm designer, I add a TextBox (for testing the result) and my custom UserControl. On the last line, I watch the event from UserControl and when it's triggered it calls the Button1Click from inside the MainForm:

```
this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 151);
this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(202, 20);
this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;

this.uControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.uControl1.Name = "uControl1";
this.uControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(304, 95);
this.uControl1.TabIndex = 0;
this.uControl1.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1Click);
```

Thus the Text property is changed.

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.textBox1.Text = "Hurrah!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If by *add this custom user control in real-time* you mean you added it at run time rather than desing time and by *I don't know how to update the event* you mean how to subscribe to this event:

Create a new public `Event` in your user control (e.g. `YourEvent`), and handle the button click by raising `YourEvent`.

Use `+=` to subscribe to that event inside your `Form`.

```
yourControl.YourEvent += YourEventHandler;
```

I guess you use Visual Studio, so just type `yourControl.YourEvent +=` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> two times and Visual Studio will create a appropriate event handler method for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to raise an event (at least according to the question provided), what you need is to put all code that executes on the event raise into the one `public` function, and from "outside", just call that function.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom event named ButtonClicked on your usercontrol, fire it when the button is clicked, and add an eventhandler in your form to handle the ButtonClicked event of the your usercontrol.

Basically you are exposing the event to the outside world from the usercontrol point of view.